# Metex multimeter constantly displaying overload

Tags: multimeter

I have a Metex M-3650CR multimeter and have just replaced the fuse and the fuse it takes is a Fast Blow 2A 250V, now my problem is that the multimeter constantly displays OL (Overload) on the screen when nothing is being tested and when something is been tested.

Also I have disconnected the internal speaker because the wires were fraying and they were too small to fix. Does this make a difference?

Any help would be appreciated,
Lachlan Fullagar

Answer (score 1):

The removal of the speaker wires should not affect the meter.

Are you sure the meter is not in "hold" mode? Could the hold button have been pressed accidentally?

If not, then we need to ask why the fuse blew. Was it subjected to a big over-voltage event? Was it a big current surge? Or was it maybe that the meter was used in Ohms, on a live circuit? Any of those things could have damaged the meter and cause it to show OL constantly. If that is the case, it's unlikely that the meter can be repaired.

Comment: I can't see a hold button on it, so it isn't that. The reason why the fuse blew is because I tried to measure a spark from a lawn mower and connected the negative (ground) wire to the cylinder head and the positive wire to spark plug wire.

Comment: @Lachiepower0402 That's a severe over-voltage condition. I suspect that the meter has been damaged. IC engine spark ignition can be 20000Volts or more.

Comment: What it is also doing is sometimes when it is on 20 in the DCV mode area it jumps from OL to 14.xx (with xx being a random number) about every 0.5 seconds it changed between OL and 14.xx. It also does this on 2 in the DCV area but with 1.4xx. I have not tried any other setting. Does that still mean it is damaged. If so is their anyway of testing if it is permanently damaged? Also a symbol the screen has just appeared of a picture of a battery, does this mean battery low?

Comment: @Lachiepower0402 It does sound like it's damaged. Test with a few known voltages (batteries) and known resistances. The damage is probably permanent, because the meter is most likely a single chip (IC) which has been damaged internally by excessive voltage. No way to repair that.

Comment: So I tried a few batteries and still nothing. Is their not even a remote way of repairing it?, sorry for being persistent.

Comment: @Lachiepower0402 If the damage is to the internal chip, as seems likely, then the only way to repair it would be to remove the chip's encapsulation, find the damage under an electron microscope, then somehow repair it. I'm not sure that repair is even possible at all at the transistor level within a chip. Sorry, it's time to buy a new meter.

Comment: The battery symbol on the display would normally mean that the meter's battery is low - but since you hit it with ~20,000 volts there's no guarantee that even the low battery detector works.